# While condition in my binary search algorithim in an Array

Tags: javascript, while-loop

```
var binarySearch = function (array, target) {
   if (array.length === 0) {
       return null;
   }
   
   if (array.length === 1) {
       if (array[0] === target) {
           return 0;
       } else {
           return null;
       }
   }
   
   let startIndex = 0;
   let endIndex = array.length - 1;

   while (startIndex <= endIndex) {
       let midIndex = Math.floor((startIndex + endIndex) / 2);

       if (array[midIndex] === target) {
           return midIndex;
       }

       if (midIndex < target) {
           startIndex = midIndex + 1;
       }

       if (midIndex > target) {
           endIndex = midIndex - 1;
       }
   }
   return null;
};

//test case
var findIndex = binarySearch([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 8); //should return null
```

I'm working on a binary search algorithim for finding a target number in a sorted array. In my test case, I have a target that doesn't exist in the array argument and I expect it to return null. It works as expected but I'm not sure how the `while` condition exits out. This is my current logic about how it's working.

On the first loop, midIndex will be equal to 2; array[2] is less than 8 so startIndex is now 3, endIndex is still 4.
On the second loop, midIndex will be equal to 3; array[3] is less than 8 so startIndex is now 4, endIndex is still 4.
On the third loop, midIndex will be equal to 4; array[4] is not equal to 8. This is the part where I'm a bit confused. I thought my while condition would keep executing, even if there is nothing to run inside since the startIndex is the same as the endIndex causing an infinite loop but that doesn't seem to be the case. I don't have a conditional statement for if the `startIndex === endIndex` but I still get returned null when I run my code. Am I understanding this correctly that the while loop will stop even if it meets the while condition if there is nothing to execute within its scope?

Comment: It's not an answer to the question you asked, so just commenting. FWIW, if it's working, it's because of the specific data you have in the array. You have an error here:

`if (midIndex < target) {`

and here:

`if (midIndex > target) {`

In both cases, you should be compare the value of `array[midIndex]`, not `midIndex` itself, with `target`. Your best bet is to do `value = array[midIndex]` and then use `value` and `target` for the comparisons. (I also suggest using `if`/`else if`/`else`.)

Comment: Your best bet here is to step through the code using the debugger built into your browser and/or IDE. That will let you go through, statement by statement, looking at the values of the variables, etc. You'll know why your loop terminates if you do that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Super helpful. I stepped through with the debugger and I totally realized why I was able to exit the loop. Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure and happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop terminates in the "not found" case because at some point, `startIndex` and `endIndex` are equal to each other but `array[midIndex]` is not equal to `target`, so you do either `startIndex = midIndex + 1` or `endIndex = midIndex - 1`. At that point, `startIndex` is greater than `endIndex` (because they used to be equal), so your `while` condition `startIndex <= endIndex` becomes false.